# Dependency Injection in Spring

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

Can you please help me??
There is a Interface X 
There are two class A and B both implements X interface .
There is a third class P and I have to inject A and B in P . How we will do this ???

Comment: This is a basic Spring question better to read some book on spring.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use `Qualifier` for that. Using `Qualifier` you can specify which instance of a class you want to inject. Assuming your bean definitions are like this

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <bean id="beanA" class="com.example.common.InterfaceX"/>

    <bean id="beanB" class="com.example.common.InterfaceX"/>

</beans>
```

Use `@Qualifier` like this

```
public class SomeRandomClass {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("beanA")
    private InterfaceX bean1;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("beanB")
    private InterfaceX bean2;

    //...
}
```

**Note**: I've changed the sample codes according to your terminology. The whole process is actually the same as always. Declare your beans at first (that's what beanA and beanB are) in your bean config file and then `@Autowired` it in the class you want to use. Now your problem is you are trying to inject two beans of the same class right? So to differentiate these two beans you'll have to have some way to tell spring which is which and thats where `@Qualifier` comes in. When declaring those beans you are giving those a bean id right? using `@Qualifier` with id you can specify which bean you actually want to inject. I hope that makes things clear. Take a look at [here](http://www.javabeat.net/qualifier-annotation-spring/) if you still have any confusion.

Comment: can you explain it in more detail because i am new to spring? where this property name came from???  I have to inject class A and B not String name in P .Please explain it in more detail .what is exampleA and ExampleB. Please